# TinyXml: Read wstring from XML file

Tags: c++, xml, sqlite, unicode

once again unicode characters are causing serious headache. Here is what I'm trying to do:
1) I'm exporting Sqlite tables (including unicode characters) to xml files (works great and unicode characters are not lost)
2) Trying to import those XML tables again ater they have been edited - works fine but unicode characters are lost.

here is the code that reads the xml file:

```
wstring input;
TiXmlElement* root = doc.FirstChildElement();
// count number of rows in xml file
TiXmlElement* counter = root->FirstChildElement();
int totalRows = 0;

while(counter != NULL) {
    totalRows += 1;
    counter = counter->NextSiblingElement();
}

// import data
wchar_t firstChar;
int check, length;
wstring finalInput;
TiXmlElement* rowElement = root->FirstChildElement();
for (int a = 1; a <= totalRows; a++) {
TiXmlElement* columnElement = rowElement->FirstChildElement();
// clear insert statement
insert = start;

for (int b = 1; b <= columns; b++) {
    node = columnElement->FirstChild();
    text = node->ToText();
    // !!! here we have the problem data gets imported as a string !!!
    input = text->Value();
```

Problem is that Value(); (function from the tinyxml files) returns const char* instead of const wchar_t. I've tried to modify the TinyXml files to return wchar_t but that resulted in some nasty errors.

My question is now: do anyone know how to read data from a xml file with tinyxml without loosing unicode characters?

thanks in advance, your help is as always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i have wchar_t (or WCHAR) version of tinyxml2 library (i converted it for my projects)

http://pastebin.com/VrgNknaa
.cpp

http://pastebin.com/NEy2jjM0
.h

Comment: thanks for your code.It can only run in windows,right? I have to modfiy to fit the linux version.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite always uses UTF-8, so ensure that your XML file stays encoded in UTF-8 when you're editing it.

To force TinyXml to read the XML file as UTF-8, use `LoadFile(filename, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8)`.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the issue, forget sqlite - it can export/import unicode strings just fine. My issue is that the Value() function in TinyXML returns a string of chars and not a wstring of wchar_t's.

this means that when I try to read the xml file and get my data back into my application that I loose any unicode characters I may have exported or added to the xml file.

somehow I need 1 or more functions from the unicode library that returns a wstring or another set of unicode enabled characters for me to read.

Comment: allright my bad. So if I make sure to save and load the xml file with UTF8 encoding then there should be no problem retrieving unicode characters like é, € etc ?

Comment: Exactly. What editor are you using? (In theory, it should not change the encoding automatically.)

Comment: If you mean IDE I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I think I discovered the problem: when tinyxml creates the xml file all special characters end up like the following: 
- Klöden -> KlÃ¶den
- Àngel -> ÃƒÂngel etc.

When I open the xml file in excel to edit, it can translate those weird characters back to the original ö, é but when I import the xml file in my application it does not translate it so I end up with the weird KlÃ¶den like names in my DB. Somehow I need to decode the xml file so I get the data i exported back in its original state.